# Haven't gotten 2 rep points back after a downvote to my answer was removed

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Today I've posted [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054834/header-files-and-multiple-class-usage-edit-forward-declarations/15054862#15054862).

I got downvoted at first, which normally lowered my reputation down by 2 points; later on, the downvote was removed, which increased my reputation by 2 points, as usual. Then I got three upvotes. Finally, one upvote was removed.

After that upvote was removed, the 2 rep points that were subtracted due to downvoting, and that were restored after the downvote was removed, **have been subtracted again**.

Then I got a further upvote, but the rep was not increased (presumably because I already earned the maximum 200 rep points today). My rep, which was 11.125 before I posted the answer, is now 11.123.

Here is a screenshot of the inconsistent information I get from my profile page and from the box at the top of the page (see the screenshot below). I also haven't cast any downvote on answers today.

Could this be a bug?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried recalcing? go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: That helped. I did not know about this feature, thank you. You can post it as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, deleted posts weren't taken into immediate consideration when calculating reputation. (That resulted in people having sometimes 100 or more "phantom" reputation, which happened when an upvoted answer was removed.) [An update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) fixed that, and caused deleted posts to be calculated shortly after deletion.

It was solved then by using a **[reputation recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation)**, you can use it one time a day, and it forces a recalculation of your reputation based on the current state of the site.

Seems like an edge case with the auto-recalc system. Triggering a manual recalc should solve it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation?recalc=true)

Comment: But that shouldn't be required?

Comment: @Arjan It will automatically be fixed at end of day.

Comment: Any source for that? I doubt any rep calculation runs daily; this really seems like an edge case, like Madara describes.